# Save NSDate to Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsdate

I am trying to save an `NSDate` to a column of type `Date` in Parse, but the following error is telling me I am getting that the value is nil:

`'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'`

This is how I'm setting my Date object:

```
NSDate *date = [self convertToNSDate:dateField.text];
[newPet setObject:date forKey:@"age"];
//I also try to save object
```

And here is my `convertToNSDate` method which converts a string with format "MM/YYYY" and returns NSDate:

```
-(NSDate *) convertToNSDate:(NSString *)dateString{
    NSString *mmyyyy = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];
    NSString *yyyymm = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [mmyyyy substringFromIndex: MAX([mmyyyy length] - 4, 0)], [mmyyyy substringToIndex:2]];
    NSString *dateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@00", yyyymm];


    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

    // Convert date object to desired output format
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"];
    dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    return date;
}
```

Is there a problem with the format? Does Parse only accept a specific format?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you checked you get a date out of your method? What's with the string processing?

Comment: Drats. I guess my real question was how to create an NSDate from an NSString, I will update my question soon and look into this, but you are right my date is null.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error was formatting a string with 00 for the `dd` format instead of 01. I changed my code to the following:

```
-(NSDate *) convertToNSDate:(NSString *)dateField{

    NSString *str = dateField;
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/yyyy"];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [formatter setTimeZone:gmt];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:str]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",date);
    return date;
}
```

This now logs the date, which was previously null. Thanks Wain for the help.